Is this a good method for reverse voltage correction
I have designed a reverse voltage correction circuit with low voltage drop using 4 MOSFETs - 2 P-Channel and 2 N-Channel.
Here is a schematic (the drains of the MOSFETs are facing outwards and the sources are facing inwards):

Here is an image when the voltage is reversed:

I have tested this using a circuit simulator (That's where I got the images from).
Will this work in a real world scenario??

Two potential issues:
If your input voltage has fast edges, you might end up with both mosfets turned on for a short period of time (google full bridge shoot through).  This will probably destroy the mosfets pretty quickly.
The second issue is that you will be limited to the Vgs range for the mosfets for your input voltage.
Linear and others make ideal diode full bridge MOSFET controllers that solve all the edge cases and provide some protection.

Actually, it is only one time that they would need to switch, when I’m plugging in the device. I’ve seen the ones from linear, but they are just too expensive!

If you are trying to protect a device from the application of reverse voltage, you just need one MOSFET.

This is for correction, not just protection.

Consider using a diode or mosfet to block reversed input voltage, and put a red LED biased the other way (with a zener and two resistors if you have a wide input range) giving a visual indication that input power was reversed.
